# stream/direct url's of youtube are not working in video.js

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming, video.js

I am using video.js to play stream/direct url of youtube videos. Many stream/direct url work in video.js but some are not working e.g

```
https://r19---sn-25ge7ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&dur=304.000&sver=3&expire=1444819060&itag=160&gcr=us&clen=4138486&gir=yes&mime=video/mp4&key=yt6&fexp=9406012,9406714,9407535,9408710,9412927,9413319,9414737,9414764,9416126,9416729,9417707,9418997,9419345,9420534,9422381,9422488,9422491&lmt=1441278683948800&source=youtube&upn=GesKDmV2r3g&mm=31&mn=sn-25ge7ney&id=o-ACNIMXJRJBqGItDzBOnMzodqkbqzhSbmWAfCo0jEAf7r&pl=20&ip=146.148.117.73&requiressl=yes&mt=1444797391&mv=m&sparams=clen,dur,gcr,gir,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,upn,expire&ms=au&signature=D361364EB21E9E90E0A68357FF816AE79AD512E259D.A1AF8432112AC912C29924420A3BB6E4E19B7
```

Video.js error:

```
"Video could not loaded either because the server fail or formate not supported"
```

Its type is mp4. Also I use the same method to play other stream/direct url's - which video.js is able to play. Is there a trick to play these (not working) url's in video.js?

Answer (score 0):

That URL responds 403 - forbidden. You can't sniff out and use You Tube URLs like this, at best they are valid for the current session only.

If you want to play You Tube videos in video.js take a look at the [videojs-youtube](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) plugin.

Comment: But this url works fine when i start a vpn like Hotspot shield. Also,some url works fine without using vpn like Hotspot shield. why it is behaving so?